# Issue displaying array data inside UIAlert View

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Essentially I would like to parse the JSON received from a url and display the data inside of alert popup.

I am able to do this with a simple array below but don't know how this can be done with an JSON array from a URL.

**Currently working:**

```
let jsonObj:[String: Any] = ["error": [
                "email": ["The email has already been taken."],
                "phone": ["The phone has already been taken."]]
                ]
if let errorMsgs = jsonObj["error"] as? [String: [String]] {
    let errMsg = errorMsgs.values.map { $0.reduce("", +) }.joined(separator: "\n")
    print(errMsg)
    self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Try again", message: errMsg)
    
}
```

**JSON Array:**

```
var structure = [Struct]()
private func fetchJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "url.com")
            else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "code=\(codeValue)".data(using: .utf8)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([Struct].self,from:data)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    struct Struct: Decodable {
        let id: Int
        let reasons: String
    }
```

**Sample JSON Array:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "reasons": "Test"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "reasons": "Test"
  }
]
```

How can I get the reasons string from the array to populate in the alert similar to above.

**UPDATE:**

To Print the records in the alert I have done the following but it only prints one record in the alert:

```
for item in self.structure {
print(item.reasons)
let errMsg = [item.reasons].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "\n")
self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Try again", message: errMsg)
}
```

Comment: How you are displaying data in your `UITableView`? and print `self.structure` after you got  the data from backed and check if you are getting anything.

Comment: Apologies that was mistake - I do not have tableview, I just use that function to parse the JSON Array

Comment: no worries. print `self.structure` and check if you are getting anything from server first.

Comment: I need to display the reason values from the array similar to the working example

Comment: Yes I am getting a result

Comment: There are two reasons strings. Which one do you want?

Comment: I have answered it. Please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created example from your code.

First of all replace your `Codable` with:

```
// MARK: - Reason
struct Reason: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let reasons: String
}

typealias Reasons = [Reason]
```

Here is your server response in `JSON` String formate:

```
let json = """
    
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "reasons": "Test"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "reasons": "Test"
      }
    ]
    
    """
```

Then I have converted it to `Data` only for testing purpose:

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
```

And you can parse it with

```
do {
    self.reasonsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Reasons.self, from:data)
    for item in self.reasonsData {
        print(item.reasons) //This will print reasons.
    }
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want all reasons in one string then replace

```
for item in self.reasonsData {
    print(item.reasons)
}
```

with

```
let errMsg = self.reasonsData.compactMap { $0.reasons }.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: Do you mind showing how your code will be used in my example? Where is reasonsData coming from

Comment: `reasonsData` is coming from `json` string which I have created manually. In your case you will get it from server.

Comment: Ok now for the message I am having smaller issue - please see my update

Comment: @MarkLyson Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @MarkLyson Please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks